# singleton and public static variable Java

Tags: java, singleton, static-variables

I have 2 options:

1. Singleton Pattern

   ```
   class Singleton{
       private static Singleton singleton = null;

       public static synchronized Singleton getInstance(){
           if(singleton  == null){
               singleton = new Singleton();
           }
           return singleton;
       }
   }
   ```
2. using a `static final` field

   ```
   private static final Singleton singleton = new Singleton();

   public static Singleton getSingleton() {
       return singleton;
   }
   ```

Whats the difference? (singlethreaded or multithreaded)

Updates: I am aware of Bill Pugh or `enum` method.
I am not looking for the correct way, but I have only used 1. Is there really any difference b/w 1 or 2?

Comment: After your updated question no difference.

Comment: this question is nothing to do with singleton. you ask about accessing a static field from synchronized/non-synchronized context. edit tags please.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani I disagree as the first option will lock each thread that attempts to get the instance and is therefore slightly less performant.

Comment: @anirbanchowdhury its not good practice to use `synchronized` an all your method. `synchronized` implementation is very expensive. I posted under other better way to use Singleton for multithreading

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main difference is that with the first option , the singleton will only be initialised when `getInstance` is called, whereas with the second option, it will get initialized as soon as the containing class is loaded.

A third (preferred) option which is lazy and thread safe is to use an enum:

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

Comment: My mistake ,somehow missed it. Have updated the question now. Also, I am aware of the ENUM singleton instance, just wanted to know the difference b.w the 2, but thanks anyways!

Answer (score 3):

There is one difference:

Solution 1 is a lazy initialization, the singleton instance will be created on the first invoke of `getInstance`

Solution 2 is a eager initialization, the singleton instance will be create when the class loades

They both are thread safe, calling the second one multi threaded is a little misleading

Comment: Well, I didnt put in the multi-threaded bit.It was edited..:P

Answer (score 2):

The 1st solutions appears to be lazier, but actually not.

A class is initialized when a static method/field is accessed for the 1st time.

It's likely that `getInstance()` is the only publicly accessible static method/field of the class. That's the point of singleton.

Then the class is initialized when someone calls `getInstance()` for the 1st time. That means the two solutions are essentially the same in laziness.

Of course, the 2nd solutions looks better and performs better.

Comment: Lazy being, no instance of Singleton being created till getInstance() is explicitly invoked. The class will obviously be loaded both times. Or am I missing something?

Comment: in the 2nd solution, the instance is only created when the class is initialized; the class is initialized only when a static method/field is accessed, i.e., when getInstance() is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

So, with the update both options above are thread-safe. However the `synchronized` option requires each thread that calls `instance` to acquire this lock thereby reducing performance if this is done a lot. Also, using `synchronized` at the method level has the potential issue of using a publicly available lock (the class itself) that therefore if some thread acquires this lock (which it could) you could end up with deadlock. The `static final` option is more performant but does not do lazy initialization of the singleton (which might not be an issue depending on the system).

Another option that allows thread-safe lazy init of the Singleton is as follows:

```
 public class MySingleton{
      private static class Builder{
          private static final MySingleton instance = new MySingleton();
      }

      public static MySingleton instance(){
           return Builder.intance;
      }
 }
```

This works because the static inner class is guarenteed to be initialized before any method in the containing class is executed.

Comment: I just reread the answer, and it doesn't have the problem i thought it had.  Sorry bout that.  :)  Removed my -1.  The answer does look a bit like word salad to me, though...and just barely touches on the real difference (lazy vs eager initialization).  You mention performance and locking, but those are not the main difference.